# Error in fetching all task from mongoDB Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, fetch, runtime-error

I am not able to find exactly what the error. I am fetching all the tasks from database. Initially it gives all task but after deleting 1 task i am getting this error . how to resolve this ?

```
/**
 * Route : /api/v1/task/fetch-task
 *
 */
const fetchTask = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tasks = await taskModel.find();
    console.log(tasks);
    if (tasks.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        message: "No Task Found",
      });
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: tasks,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Error Image :
[image]

I tried the above mention code .

Comment: What is the definition of your model? Do you have a document in the database which is `_id: "fetch-task"`? You could check that by using the shell. If so you may need to delete it if your model is expecting the `_id` field up contain ObjectIds (which I believe it does but default)

Answer (score 0):

Initially I created my Routes like this :

```js
router.get("/:id", getsingleTask);
router.post("/create-task", createTask);
router.get("/fetch-task", fetchTask);
router.put("/update-task/:id", updateTask);
router.delete("/delete-task/:id", deleteTask);
```

Now I changed my Routes to

```js
router.post("/create-task", createTask);
router.get("/fetch-task", fetchTask);
router.get("/:id", getsingleTask);
router.put("/update-task/:id", updateTask);
router.delete("/delete-task/:id", deleteTask);
```